# Expresiones regulares (expresion para ingresar solo correos @gmail)

Tags: javascript, php, html, validación

Tengo una pagina la cual realiza envíos de correo al realizar cierta actividad... Mi pagina solo envía correos a las cuentas @gmail, si tienes otra cuenta, como por ejemplo @hotmail el correo nunca te llegara, estoy investigando porque ocurre eso, pero como medida preventiva o momentánea estaba pensando en alguna expresión regular para que me verifique que el correo que el usuario intenta registrar sea SI O SI @gmail, la expresión que tengo hasta ahora es esta: (no funciona)
`expresion_correo= /\w+@+[gmail]\w+\.+[a-z]/;`

Esta expresión no funciona, ya que me valida por ejemplo este correo `test@gm.com.ar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que podrías probar con esta expresión regular si lo que deseas es que solo sean correos con **@gmail.com**

```
[^@ \t\r\n]+@gmail\.com
```

Pero si deseas que vaya cualquier otra cosa luego de **@gmail**, es decir **gmail.org** o **gmail.algunotrodominio** puedes usar ésta:

```
[^@ \t\r\n]+@gmail+\.[^@ \t\r\n]+
```

> Las expresiones regulares se pueden hacer un tanto difíciles cuando no tenemos experiencia. Herramientas como esta: [I Hate Regex](https://ihateregex.io/) me han facilitado bastante el entenderlas dinámicamente.

Answer (score 0):

Usar expresiones regulares es la mejor manera de lograr esto:

Intenta implementar esta función:

### Editado:

Validación de solamente GMAIL

```
function isValidEmail(email) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Aquí está el ejemplo de expresión regular que acepta unicode:

```
const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```

Pero tenga en cuenta que no se debe confiar solo en la validación de JavaScript. JavaScript se puede desactivar fácilmente. Esto también debe validarse en el lado del servidor.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de lo anterior en acción:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
  const $result = $("#result");
  const email = $("#email").val();
  $result.text("");

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $result.text(email + " is valid :)");
    $result.css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $result.text(email + " is not valid :(");
    $result.css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("#email").on("input", validate);
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for=email>Enter an email address:</label>
<input id="email">
<h2 id="result"></h2>
```

Comment: Hola @Hernando, Bienvenido! tu respuesta esta bien, es una expresión regular la cual verifica que el correo que se ingreso sea valido, pero lo que yo necesito es que el correo sea `@gmail` no puede ser ni `@hotmail` ni `@outlook` ni algún otro tipo de correo, solo `@gmail`

Answer (score 0):

###### Observaciones

El regex que usas es `\w+@+[gmail]\w+\.+[a-z]`. Te agrego unas observaciones:

- `[gmail]` detecta cualquier caracter dentro de corchetes, no detectará 'gmail' sino un caracter, sea g, m, i o l. Soy redundante: no capturará todos a la vez, solo un caracter.
- tienes `\w+` después de gmail, esto obligaría a que exista almenos un caracter inmediatamente después de 'gmail'.
- `[a-z]` solo detecta un caracter en minúsculas
- `@+` detecta 1 o más '@' consecutivos
- `\w+` detecta solo palabras sin caracteres especiales como: '-' o '.' ... 'my.correo@gmail.com' fallaría

###### Recomendación

Puedes textualmente escribir al final `tu.regex@gmail\.com`, donde `tu.regex` estaría sujeto a modificación.